# Reading XML using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, ssis, xml-parsing, xmldocument

This is my feed.

```
<feed xml:lang="">
   <title>NEWS.com.au | Top Stories</title>
   <link rel="self" href="http://feeds.news.com.au/public/atom/1.0/news_top_stories_48_48.xml"/>
   <link rel="alternate" href="http://news.com.au"/>
   <id>http://news.com.au</id>
   <rights/>
   <entry>
      <title>F1’s glaring issues exposed</title>
      <link href="www.google.com"/>
      <author>
         <name>STEVE LARKIN</name>
      </author>
      <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" length="2373" href="abc.jpg"/>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      .....
   </entry>
</feed>
```

This is how i am reading the xml.

```
    string downloadfolder = "C:/Temp/Download/abc.xml";
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(downloadfolder);
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
    string xpath_title = "atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:title";
    XmlNodeList nodes_title = xml.SelectNodes(xpath_title, nsmgr);

    foreach (XmlNode node_title in nodes_title)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node_title.InnerText);
    }

 string xpath_author = "atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:author";
    XmlNodeList nodes_author = xml.SelectNodes(xpath_author, nsmgr);

    foreach (XmlNode node_author in nodes_author)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node_author.InnerText);
    }

string xpath_link = "atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:link";
    XmlNodeList nodes_link = xml.SelectNodes(xpath_link, nsmgr);

    foreach (XmlNode node_link in nodes_link)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node_link.Attributes["href"].Value);
    }
```

I want to read title, link, author inside the `<entry>` node. i am defining xpath and then iterating the values of each node is there any other way to define xpath once and then iterate all the values from the `<entry>` node

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the data that  you "read"? Obviously, you're not trying to do `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: thanks @JohnSaunders i will store the data in a datatable.

Comment: Are you trying to download the image itself?

Comment: You can help yourself by being more clear about what you're trying to do. For instance, you say you're using SSIS. Is this for a script task, or a script component in a data flow, and if a transform, what kind is it? Exactly which parts of the XML are you trying to output, either to the script component outputs or wherever? You don't have a simple parsing problem, you have a problem of parsing the XML to use it for some particular purpose.

Comment: mate i said i am using SSIS because people may come up with a linq solution so it is not supported in SSIS 2008. And i want to read everything inside the <entry> node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To operate on all child nodes of `<entry>` node, you can stop your XPath at `/atom:entry`. Then inside the loop, select each child nodes as you want, for example :

```
......
String xpath = "atom:feed/atom:entry";
XmlNodeList nodes2 = xml.SelectNodes(xpath, nsmgr);

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes2)
{
    var title = node.SelectSingleNode("./atom:title", nsmgr).InnerText;
    var link1 = node.SelectSingleNode("./atom:link[1]", nsmgr).Attributes["href"].Value;
    //go on to select and operate on the rest child nodes
    //.......
}
```

Notice that you need to add a dot (`.`) at the beginning of the XPath to make XPath context relative to current `node` instead of the entire XML document.

Answer (score 0):

To read the `href` attribute you will need to modify your xpath expression to...

```
string xpath = "atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:link";
```

this will iterate through all links within entries. Then, you will need read that specific attibute's value instead of reading the `InnerText`

```
Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

Now, if you want to read everything inside the `entry` elements, xpath will quickly get your code a bit messy. A cleaner solution, IMHO, would be using xml serialization so that you can easily parse/serialize "entries" into POCO objects. Then, you can do whatever you want with these objects

Comment: thanks for the solution it works fine but do i need to define seperate xpath to read title and author ?

Comment: @user3754676 that's exactly what I'm saying, you can always iterate through all entries and use the `XmlNode ` methods to extract this data inside the `foreach` loop

Comment: @user3754676 or, use xml serialization instead